# R nonlinear regression of cumulative X and Y data

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression, nonlinear-functions, cumulative-frequency

I'm trying to figure how to make a nonlinear regression of some cumulative data of X and Y values. The dataset is based on cumulative items and their respective cumulated demand. I have a plot that looks like this

[image: cumulative demand of cumulative items]

based on the following observation of 5299 items, which is available here: [abc.csv datafile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qt6a50GhZw5hueQ9gxhpIP29ZDt9yqt3/view?usp=sharing)

and I would like to fit a model that can explain it quite neatly. Given the plot, I reckon that there is a high degree of detail. Hence, I would believe that it would be possible to find a function that would explain the data with very high accuracy.

The problem is, however, that I find myself trying to fit a model with `nls()` by trial and error. Furthermore, some of the functions that I've tried give me some explanation, but not in full detail. For instance

> nlm <- nls(abc$Cumfreq ~c*(1-exp(-a*abc$noe))+b, data=abc, 
>               start = list(a=4.14, b=0.21, c=0.79))

Yields me:

[image: With regression]

My question is: how do I obtain a regression with a better fit? Is there a function in R or another way of achieving this? (fingers crossed for a math genius out there)

Comment: What is the goal? Prediction or inference?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I guess the goal is prediction.

Comment: Then I would fit a GAM. Don't forget to validate/crossvalidate.